# problem while installing brave browser

Tags: brave

Ignoring file 'brave-browser-beta.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Can anyone explain this to me? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to install a BETA version. If not sure what it is I suggest you do not install it. Best to use a non beta version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the command you copied was truncated. The files in that directory need to be have a ".list" extension. If you rename the file brave-browser-beta.lis. to brave-browser-beta.list it should work.
Rename from lis to list.

Answer (score 0):

[Instructions](https://brave.com/linux/#release-channel-installation) are available for the Installation of the Brave browser, stable or beta. Make sure you copy/paste **exactly** as indicated:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com/ stable main"|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-beta.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brave-browser-beta
```

You can use Software & Updates > Other software to remove the wrong entry that was mistyped or wrongly copied.